# Digital Effects Unit

Tags: digital

I'm after a effects unit for just some simple plate reverb and maybe some delay on two mono channels. I'm on a shoestring budget, so the cheaper the better.

I've seen [Alesis MidiVerb 4](http://www.alesis.com/midiverb4)'s around for around $100 on the second hand market. It looks great and exactly what we need, but it's from around 1990. Is this going to be an issue? What would I be missing from a 20-year-old unit over a brand new unit (besides a big hole in my wallett).

We're only after simple reverb and delay for vocals.

Comment: This question is too localised and will go out of date. It would be better to ask what to look for in a digital effects unit

Comment: @Will - I've asked a few questions like that already and I kept getting localised answers. I figured I may as well just ask what i want to know. Also, if I were to ask "Whats the downside of a unit from 1990" then that's the same question, worded so it doens't go out of date.

Answer (score 3):

My biggest complaint with the MidiVerb series is they tend to be noisy. All the MidiVerbs I've used introduced a fair bit of hiss.

My preference would be a Lexicon MPX110 for a budget reverb unit. I really like Lexicon's reverbs and despite the simple interface, it's actually pretty tweakable.

Comment: Is that noise issue something that's related to the age of the device, or just the Midiverb in general?

Comment: It's a common problem with Alesis gear from that period in time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Alesis NanoVerb](http://alesis.com/nanoverb) is an 18-bit digital effects processor.

[image: NanoVerb Front Panel]

From the site:

```
16 programs, with 16 variations each, for a total of 256 presets
Analog wet/dry mix control
Adjustable input and output gains
Stereo inputs automatically switch to dual mono when signal is only present on the left jack
Minimized signal path for optimal sound quality
Signal/clip LED control for easy visual monitoring
Rugged, compact design for years of reliable performance
Bypass control with footswitch, sold separately
```